# Extract value of Polars literal

Tags: python-polars

If I have a Polars literal, how can I extract the value?

```py
import polars as pl

expr = pl.lit(0.5)

val = float(expr)
# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'Expr'
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Like so:

```py
val = pl.select(expr).item()
```

Explanation: a polars literal is an Expr object. An Expr object can be evaluated using [`pl.select()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.select.html). That returns a DataFrame. To get the scalar value from the DataFrame, you can use  [`DataFrame.item()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.item.html).

Note: `.item()` was added [in release 0.15.9 of polars](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.15.9). If you are using a version prior to this, you can use `pl.select(expr)[0, 0]` as an alternative.